# Parsing log with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, logging

I need extract only "40:37.298s" from:

```
Total time: 40:37.298s
```

using JS, but I`m new in JS, can some one help?

Answer (score 6):

```
> 'Total time: 40:37.298s'.substr(12)
'40:37.298s'
```

If you want to use a regex for more flexibility:

```
> /([0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+s)/.exec('Total time: 40:37.298s')[1]
'40:37.298s'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one:

```
var str = "Total time: 40:37.298s";
str.split(": ")[1]
```

In most cases I prefer splitting on some known pivot, rather than trying to extract a specific substring (as others have shown) for the following reasons:

- It's more flexible; this will still work if the first part of the string contains slight variations (but the substring method won't)
- It's easier to see what's being extracted (but the substring method requires that I manually count positions in the string to verify that I'm selecting the right thing)

Answer (score 1):

```
var time = 'Total time: 40:37.298s';

time = time.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d+s/);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypzgJ/

Answer (score 0):

the substring method is what you're looking for:

```
"Total time: 40:37.298s".substring("Total time: ".length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "Total time: 40:37.298s".replace(/^.*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}s)/g,'$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = 'Total time: 40:37.298s';
var pattern = /\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}s/g;
var res = pattern.exec(item);
```

That is:

- \d{1,2} one or two digits
- \:  the ':' char
- \d{2}   two digits
- .  the '.' char
- \d{3}  three digits
- s   the 's' char

Comment: Note, that Regexp `.exec()` will assign matches in an Array to the `res`, so to get the actual matched value from the code above, you'll need to query `res[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a RegEx like `[:\.0-9]*s`

for example

```
yourText.match("regex")
```

in your case it will be

```
"Total time: 40:37.298s".match("[:\.0-9]*s")[0]
```

It will return `40:37.298s`